# gives children practice thinking or practice to think (to infinitive)

Tags: to-infinitive

> This helps them analyze situations from different perspectives. Pretending to be someone else, with all the gestures, actions, and language that involves, gives children practice *thinking* divergently as they consider different things they can pretend to do.

Can I rewrite like: gives children practice "to think" instead of "thinking"?

Answer (score 1):

No. Swapping the gerund for the infinitive wouldn't work here.

The construction here is similar to **to give someone practice [at] an activity**. The activity here has to be a noun, therefore you need to use the gerund (noun) form "thinking".

Comment: I think it's a present participle; not a gerund

Comment: @BEBYGONES "Thinking" can be a present participle, as in "I was thinking about something", but that isn't its function in the example.  In English the gerund and present participle have the same form (verb+ing), but different functions.

Comment: In fact, (in) thinking  but without 'in' it's no more a 'gerund'.

Comment: One could also argue that in/at is simply omitted. Another example: "I need to get some more practice [at] playing the piano, before I perform at the concert."  If you were to swap this for "more practice to play the piano", it will sound non-native, or distinctly odd.